# Rokhlin lemma for arbitrary infinite groups.

Tags: gr.group-theory, ergodic-theory, ds.dynamical-systems

Let $G$ be an at most countable discrete group acting freely on a standard probability measure space $X$ in a measure preserving way.

It is well known that if $G$ is a finite group then this action admits a fundamental domain. As pointed out by Andreas below, by Rokhlin lemma, if $G$ contains an element of infinite order we can find an $(\varepsilon, N)$-fundamentalish domain $U$, where the latter is defined as follows:

Call a set $U\subset X$ an $(\varepsilon, N)$-fundamentalish domain iff there exist $N$  elements $g_1, \ldots, g_N$ of $G$ such that the sets $g_i(U)$ are pairwise disjoint and the measure of their union is at least $1-\varepsilon$.

> **Question:** If $G$ is an infinite group, $N_0$ is a natural number, $\varepsilon_0$ is a  positive real number, does there exist an $(\varepsilon, N)$-fundamentalish domain with $\varepsilon<\varepsilon_0$ and $N>N_0$?

For example when the action is profinite and "transitive on each level", then clearly answer is positive: there exist $(0,N)$-fundamentalish domains for arbitrary large $N$.

Comment: Exactly :-) Is there a Rokhlin lemma for action of an arbitary group (i.e. a Tarski monster)? I'll reformulate the question accordingly


Answer (score 9):

If you fix $N$ and group elements $g_1$, ..., $g_N \in G$, then your question becomes closely related to tilings of groups. Specifically, in Chapter 2, section 2 of "[Entropy and Isomorphism Theorems for Actions of Amenable Groups](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02790325)," Ornstein and Weiss prove:

Let $G$ be a countable group acting freely and measure preservingly on a standard probability space $(X, \mu)$. Fix a finite set $T \subseteq G$. If for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is a measurable set $U \subseteq X$ such that the $T$-translates of $U$ are disjoint and $\mu(T \cdot U) > 1 - \epsilon$, then $T$ tiles $G$ in the sense that there is a set of centers $C \subseteq G$ such that the sets $Tc$ ($c \in C$) partition $G$.

They also prove that if $G$ is amenable then the converse holds. So if $G$ is amenable and $T$ is a tile for $G$, then for every free probability measure preserving action of $G$ and every $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $(\epsilon, |T|)$-fundamentalish domain. Thus a natural question is: which amenable groups admit arbitrarily large finite tiles?

Weiss called a group $G$ MT (mono-tileable) if for every finite set $F \subseteq G$ there is a finite tile $T \subseteq G$ containing $F$. In "[Monotileable amenable groups](https://books.google.com/books?id=NDJ0rRuSMScC&pg=PA257&lpg=PA257&dq=monotileable+amenable+groups&source=bl&ots=DpqekXyi_H&sig=ShnrG6LH5nqIqT1QKGWVcxJFXlM&hl=en&ei=aovBTs3_D8W02wWAs-GxBQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result#v=onepage&q=monotileable%20amenable%20groups&f=false)," Weiss proved that all solvable groups and all residually finite groups are MT. In "[Elementary Amenable Groups](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/illinois-journal-of-mathematics/volume-24/issue-3/Elementary-amenable-groups/10.1215/ijm/1256047608.full)," Chou proved that all elementary amenable groups and all free products of non-trivial groups are MT. So in particular, your question has a positive answer whenever the group $G$ is elementary amenable. A stronger tiling condition, called ccc, is studied in chapter 4 of "[Groups Colorings and Bernoulli Subflows](https://web.archive.org/web/20120204105310/http://www-personal.umich.edu/%7Ebseward/Files/Group%20Colorings%20and%20Bernoulli%20Subflows.pdf)" (this paper is in preparation). Weaker properties of poly-MT and poly-ccc are studied in "[Burnside's Problem, spanning trees, and tilings](https://web.archive.org/web/20120204105316/http://www-personal.umich.edu/%7Ebseward/Files/Burnside%27s%20Problem,%20Spanning%20Trees,%20and%20Tilings.pdf)." To the best of my knowledge these are the only papers which study tilings of countable groups.

Comment: Thanks Brandon, curiously, this question was more-or-less an outcome of my reading the arxiv preprint you updated a couple of days ago...